# fading line (gradient) in IE10

Tags: html, css, gradient, internet-explorer-10

I'm using the following code to display a gradient line: http://jsfiddle.net/JoshMesser/55ZfK/ (found that via this website http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/10375/sexy-css3-fading-line/p1). This works perfectly for Chrome and Firefox, but does not show anything in IE10..

```
.sexy_line{ 
display:block;
border:none;
color:white;
height:1px;
background:black;
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, 50% 50%, 0, 50% 50%, 350, from(#000), to(#fff));
```

}

Being far from a CSS expert, some googling led me to http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/graphics/cssgradientbackgroundmaker/ but I don't seem to be able to get the desired effect using the -ms-linear-gradient function.

So my question: what code do I need to get a nice gradient line (fading towards both sides, just like the one in the jsfiddle example) working in IE10?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

It creates code for cross-browser background.